What is the Ornstein Uhlenbeck process? Is it basically used to add noise to any dynamical system?
Sorry if this comes across as a silly question. However, I am still unable to wrap my head around the applications for the Ornstein Uhlenbeck process. I understand that is a standard example used to show how SDEs work. My specific question is, can we use this process somehow to add uncertainty to a deterministic system? Suppose I have a dynamical system represented using ODEs: will literally add the Wiener process term and the mean reversion rate term to the ODE and transform the ODE into an SDE?
For instance, the actual ODE equation in discretized form is

$$\large v_{t+\Delta t} = v_t + g \Delta t.$$

Adding the OU terms to the above equation, we obtain ODE converted to SDE:

$$\large v_{t+\Delta t} = v_t + g \Delta t + \theta (\mu -v_t) + \sigma \sqrt{\Delta t}\, \epsilon_t.$$


Yes to all your questions, except that I am imagining  Norbert W$\color{red}{ie}$ner turning around  in his grave. Added later: thanks for the fix.

Sorry, that was a typo
! And thanks for confirming!

:) I met someone here on MSE who insisted to spell it Weiner because that's what he saw in 50% of the cases on the internet. (And that was before chatGPT) :)

Okay, now I am pretty sure I misspelled it when I wrote a couple of my mid semester project reports.
